# Using GNU Standard Directory Variables inside executable

Tags: gnu, autoconf, automake

Often one needs the location of one of the standard GNU directories inside the executable. Unfortunately GNU autoconf does not provide a standard way to do this but suggests several work around, each having different disadvantages, a common way to access the installed location is this to add preprocess define for the location in `CPPFLAGS`:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -DDATADIR='"$(datadir)"'
```

However, the GNU Autoconf manual's section for [defining directories](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Defining-Directories) contains the following sentence:

> Note that all the previous solutions hard wire the absolute name of these directories in the executables, which is not a good property. You may try to compute the names relative to prefix, and try to find prefix at runtime, this way your package is relocatable.

Is there a library or any standard way to compute the GNU directories inside an executable as suggested in the quoted paragraph? Would that have other disadvantages compared to the preprocessor define mentioned above?

Comment: That probably means you can compute the prefix from the executable path, if the binary is located in a standard GNU directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the docs are rather clear about this: The standard way is to not make any assumptions about the absolute path, and use relative paths instead. Especially you should not make any assumptions about `${prefix}`

So if your application needs to access shared data, access it via `../share/foo/foodata.txt` rather than using `/usr/local/share/foo/foodata.txt`; this way you can easily re-locate your application.

Afaik, there is no external library that computes the standard paths for you, based on your calling binary.

This is probably for two reasons:

- if the binary indeed uses the standard paths, then it's trivial to calculate those paths yourself (using relative paths). what would a library do better?
- if the binary does *not* use the standard paths (e.g. because the builder used something like the following (admittedly hypothetical) example), then the task of resolving these paths is virtually impossible; so a library won't help you either

ex:

```
./configure --sbindir=/home/me/sbin --bindir=/opt/foo/bin
make pkglibdir=/usr/lib/goo/
make install libdir=/usr/local/foo/lib/
```

A helper-library (or your application) might record all those paths into some auxiliary file (for additional lookups if the standard-paths fail), but I think the biggest problem is that there is no defined place where to store that file

- `libdir` or `datadir` are obviously not good (as the data should help resolve these paths, so cannot rely on them)
- putting the data into the same directory as the application binary breaks the assumption of `bindir` only containing executables.
- putting the data *into* the application binary might require that binary to be modified during `make install`, which sounds very dirty as well.